# How to create an abstract class, then intercept it's descendant method

Tags: c#, ninject, aop, interceptor

I'm trying to separate "contracts" from "implementation". Security features are "contracts" too (apart of implementation of how exactly those features work).

So I'm trying to write something like this:

```
public abstract class SomeServiceContract
{
    [Authorize]
    public abstract void SomeMethod();
}

public class SomeServiceImpl : SomeServiceContract
{
    public override void SomeMethod()
    {
        // this can just be implemented, no need to worry about access rigts 
    }
}
```

The only purpose of the Authorize attribute (which is inherited) is to be checked in an interceptor. But to be "interceptable", a method must be virtual, or it can't be wrapped by Ninject, for example. And I can't make an overridden method to be virtual.

How else can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is virtual by default.

The restriction is only if it is marked with "sealed".

If you override method from abstract class - the method is virtual. If from interface - the method is "virtual sealed", unless you marked it as "virtual"

Comment: So is it true that I'll get both attribute inheritance and "wrappable" methods suitable for interception in a dynamic proxy?